# Firebase pushing notification to chat members when a new message gets delivered without cloud functions

Tags: python, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a chat app in flutter/firebase and I'm using firebase cloud messaging to send notifications and I've successfully send notifcations to the user using the firebase console.

Then I built my app server using python and I've send notifications to all users using this code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging,firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("C:/Users/MASTER/PycharmProjects/pythonFCMTest/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
firestore.firestore.Watch

def sendPush(title, msg, registration_token, dataObject=None):
    # See documentation on defining a message payload.
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        notification=messaging.Notification(
            title=title,
            body=msg
        ),

        data=dataObject,
        tokens=registration_token,
    )

    # Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    # registration token.
    response = messaging.send_multicast(message)

    # Response is a message ID string.
    print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```

Now I want to send notifications to other chat members when a new message gets delivered, I know that I can do this using firebase cloud functions but they are now part of the paid version and I don't want to upgrade my version just for testing these features so is there any other way to send notifications to users based on changes in the firestore database?

Comment: siba36 , do let me know if below recommendation were helpful, or are you looking for some other information.

Comment: Posted an update on below answer below with more information,hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging itself is still completely free, and the cost even if occurred would be purely for hosting/serving the images from Cloud Storage. If you were to use a different host for the images, you could still pay nothing for Google Cloud overall.
[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is a free Push Notification service (previous version known as Google Cloud Messaging).                                                               FCM is a separate service from  [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)                                                                                                                                                                     Like I mentioned above, the push notification feature which is bundled with the FCM service is included free for any Firebase Plan.
The [Pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) already shows the included Free products like Analytics, App Indexing, Authentication, Cloud Messaging, Crash Reporting, Dynamic Links, Invites, Notifications & Remote Config.Also, there is no limit to the number of users you plan to connect using FCM.

**UPDATE:**

You may try setting up servers with SDK and configure these to listen to changes to the database.An event listener may receive several different types of events. This mode of data retrieval is supported in Java, Node.js and Python Admin SDKs.Check the links for more details on this:
[Listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) and
[Set data and listen for changes using the Apple platforms, Android, Web, Admin SDKs, or the REST API.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database#next_steps)

Comment: I know FCM is free but I was asking for a method to send notifications based on changes in the database (for example when a new message arrives ) and that's is done with cloud functions, so I was asking for another method to do this without the use of cloud functions